# Include only partial .pug file? Is it not possible?

Tags: pug

For the life of me I can't figure out how to include only **a specific part** of a .pug file. Suppose I have *tutorials.pug*:

```
block tut1
  p Some tutorial
block tut2
  p Some other Tut
block tut3
  p And then some other tut
```

Then in my main.pug I'ld like to go:

```
extends tutorials
h2 Hey, enjoy the second Tutorial!
block append tut2
```

without any other blocks showing up at all. Is this simple thing not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **mixins** could be what you're looking for. A [`mixin`](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html) is made exactly for the purpose that you want: Including a piece of template code as an isolated snippet. A [`block`](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html) on the other hand is made for template definitions. With blocks, you can define a template page, which other pages can inherit from and then append or replace those blocks. For your use case, you're probably better of with structuring the functionality using mixins, if you want isolated imports of a specific part of a common page.